# What is the difference between symmetry and hermitian ?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am really confused now.

Transformation, T , is called hermitian if ( T(x), y ) = ( y , T(x) )

Transformation, T , is called symmetric if ( T(x),y)=(y, T(x))

I think that difference between these two is whether it is real or complex euclidean space.

In euclidean space, inner product is complex number.

If T is hermitian, then how can (T(x).x)=(x.T(x)) be true with no conjugate sign?

Comment: "I think that difference between these two is whether it is real or complex euclidean space". That's correct. Usually symmetry is defined only for real operators/matrices while hermitian is defined in the complex case.

Comment: If hermitian is defined in complex case, does that mean that inner product is  complex number??